# pandas dataframe ploted as a table in matplotlibm but the first column missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I would like to plot a pandas dataframe as a table in matplotlib.

The dataframe (df):

```
  name   wait_value
  cscas   2
  cscas   6
  dgref   3
  dgref   7
```

I used :

```
new_df = df.groupby(['name'])['wait_value'].mean().to_frame()
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axarr[0].axis('off')
axarr[0].axis('tight')
axarr[0].table(cellText= new_df.values, colLabels=('ave_wait_value'), loc='center')
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

But, the table has only one column "ave_wait_value". I need two columns:

```
   ave_wait_value
     4
     5
```

How can I add the "name" column to the table?

I also tried :

```
new_df.rename(columns = {0:'name', 1:'ave_wait_value'}, inplace =True)
```

But, it did not work.

Also, I need to calculate std.dev for each "name" and put it as a column in the same table, how to design the query ?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name information is there; it's just stored in the index. To convert the index to a column, use `reset_index`:

```
In [45]: df.groupby(['name'])['wait_value'].mean().to_frame()
Out[45]:
       wait_value
name
cscas           4
dgref           5

In [46]: df.groupby('name')['wait_value'].mean().reset_index()
Out[46]:
    name  wait_value
0  cscas           4
1  dgref           5
```

To get both the mean and standard deviation, use `agg`:

```
In [49]: df.groupby('name')['wait_value'].agg(['mean', 'std']).reset_index()
Out[49]:
    name  mean       std
0  cscas     4  2.828427
1  dgref     5  2.828427
```